# How to return an asset url from objective C to javascript in iOS cordova project?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova, alassetslibrary

I am trying a cordova project for ios.
I got an asset url in my log, and I tried with that url in my code and it works fine.
But, I need that asset-url as return value from the objective C to the javascript.

```
- (void)saveImageDataToLibrary:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{
    self.callbackId = command.callbackId;
    NSData* imageData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]];

    UIImage* image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData] autorelease];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

    UIImage *viewImage = image;  // --- mine was made from drawing context
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    // Request to save the image to camera roll
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[viewImage CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[viewImage imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error");
        } else {
        NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL);
        }
    }];
    [library release];
}

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo{
    // Was there an error?
    if (error != NULL)
    {
        // Show error message...
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",error);
        CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus: CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:error.description];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[result toErrorCallbackString: self.callbackId]];
    }
    else  // No errors
    {
        // Show message image successfully saved
        NSLog(@"IMAGE SAVED!");
        CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus: CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"Image saved"];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[result toSuccessCallbackString: self.callbackId]];
    }
}
```

Here....
This code gives me the log....

```
NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL);
```

I would like to get this `assetURL` as my return value to my javascript,where am calling this function...

I've stucked here for a week...

Help me to relieve from this...

Thnx in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank you all** who've tried this.... I got it after some searches....
I've added the code after that NSLog line in the code shown above...It is as follows...

```
NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL);
        CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus: CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:[assetURL absoluteString]];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[result toSuccessCallbackString: self.callbackId]];
```